# SAP Tables RFC Table function

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to extract the data from SAP Tables and also providing the date range with below formula mentioned :

`ERDAT GE '20230501' AND ERDAT LE '20230504'`

I am getting error :

[image]

Please advise me the correct formula

Regards
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error like yours.

[image]

I got this error when **I used a dataset parameter without creating**.

Here, `folderpath` is a dataset parameter but it's not created.

[image]

Make sure that you create that parameter in your dataset before usage.

[image]